# Remove the chapter number in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, koma-script, titlesec, scrpage2

I am using the latest version of the LaTeX template of Matthias Pospiech, see http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2016/05/09/latex-thesis-template-3-2-4-released/.

In my MWE I try to achieve the following: I created a chapter with `\chapter[Chapter 1: Headline]{Headline}` and in the ToC it is printed as `1 Chapter 1: Headline`.

I want to remove the first `1`, so that `Chapter 1: Headline` will be displayed in combination that the styling of the chapter itself on the page where the chapter begins and the styling of the header of the pages should be still the same. So only removing the chapter number `1` without changing something else in the document.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,version=last,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{templatetools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[automark,komastyle]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\ifcsdef{chapter}
    {\usepackage{titlesec}}
    {\usepackage{titlesec} \csundef{chapter}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\IfPackageLoaded{scrpage2}{
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
}{
   \pagestyle{scrplain}
}
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \ohead{\pagemark}
   \ihead{\headmark}
   \ofoot[\pagemark]{}
}{
   \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
}
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \automark[section]{chapter}
}{
   \automark[subsection]{section}
}
\IfDefined{chapter}{
   \setheadsepline{.4pt}[\color{black}]
}
}
\IfPackageLoaded{titlesec}{
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\Large \color{black}}
  {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
   \Huge~\thechapter \filright}
  {1pt}
  {
   \titlerule \vspace{0.9pc}\vspace{-\parskip}
   \filright 
   \IfColorDefined{sectioncolor}{\color{sectioncolor}}{}   
  }
  [\color{black} \vspace{0.9pc} \filright {\titlerule}]
}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{frontmatter}{
   \newcommand{\frontmatter}{
      \pagenumbering{roman}
   }
}{}
\@ifundefined{mainmatter}{
   \newif\if@mainmatter\@mainmattertrue
   \newcommand{\mainmatter}{
      \pagenumbering{arabic}
      \setcounter{page}{1}
   }
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\IfPackageLoaded{scrpage2}{\pagestyle{scrheadings}}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\addchap{General Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter[Chapter 1: Headline]{Headline}
\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a known fact that a KOMA class and `titlesec/titletoc` should not be used together

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You missed out on a chance to paraphrase Jane Austen. :-) How about, "It is a truth universally acknowledged, that the KOMA classes and `titlesec`/`titletoc` should not be used together."

Comment: @Mico: Having 'Persuasion' and 'Pride and Prejudice' that 'Emma' should not use `KOMA` **and** `titlesec`, neither in 'Mansfield Park' nor in 'Northanger Abbey' ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Good one! :-)

Comment: @Mico: Damn, I forgot 'Sense and Sensibility' :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that neither package `titletoc` nor package `titlesec` should be used with a KOMA-Script class. Package `scrpage2` is deprecated for years. Its successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

You could add

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numwidth=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\noentrynumber
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand*\noentrynumber[1]{}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
```

to remove the chapter numbers from TOC and page header. Note that the chapter entries in TOC then will be controlled by package `tocbasic`.

Remove package `titletoc` and use

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numwidth=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\noentrynumber
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand\noentrynumber[1]{}
```

[image]

[image]

But I think it would be better to remove the optional argument of the chapters (and the manuel numbering in it) and insert the chapter prefix in TOC by changing `entrynumberformat` for chapterentries:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumber
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand\chapterentrynumber[1]{\def\autodot{:}\chaptername\ #1}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip}
```

Then you have to run the code three times to get:

[image]

Code:

```
% Disclamer:
% The following code is mainly the MWE from the question.
% Note that you should not use packages titlesec and titletoc
% together with a KOMA-Script class.
% Package `scrpage2` is deprecated. Its successor is scrlayer-scrpage.
% So I do not recommend to use the following code.
\documentclass[paper=a4,version=last,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{templatetools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[automark,komastyle]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\ifcsdef{chapter}
    {\usepackage{titlesec}}
    {\usepackage{titlesec} \csundef{chapter}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\IfPackageLoaded{scrpage2}{
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
}{
   \pagestyle{scrplain}
}
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \ohead{\pagemark}
   \ihead{\headmark}
   \ofoot[\pagemark]{}
}{
   \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
}
\IfElseDefined{chapter}{
   \automark[section]{chapter}
}{
   \automark[subsection]{section}
}
\IfDefined{chapter}{
   \setheadsepline{.4pt}[\color{black}]
}
}
\IfPackageLoaded{titlesec}{
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\Large \color{black}}
  {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
   \Huge~\thechapter \filright}
  {1pt}
  {
   \titlerule \vspace{0.9pc}\vspace{-\parskip}
   \filright 
   \IfColorDefined{sectioncolor}{\color{sectioncolor}}{}
  }
  [\color{black} \vspace{0.9pc} \filright {\titlerule}]
}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{frontmatter}{
   \newcommand{\frontmatter}{
      \pagenumbering{roman}
   }
}{}
\@ifundefined{mainmatter}{
   \newif\if@mainmatter\@mainmattertrue
   \newcommand{\mainmatter}{
      \pagenumbering{arabic}
      \setcounter{page}{1}
   }
}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[% <- added
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumber
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand\chapterentrynumber[1]{\def\autodot{:}\chaptername\ #1}% <- added
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip}%<- added

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\IfPackageLoaded{scrpage2}{\pagestyle{scrheadings}}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\addchap{General Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Headline}% <- changed
\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But one issue. The header of the pages, I see now "1 Headline", but I would like to have "Chapter 1: Headline", so the same text as in the ToC.

Comment: You have to redefine `\chaptermarkformat`. See my updated answer.